# Lavaan model output problem: labels are truncated

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I just ran a huge model and am having trouble making out all the results in the summary. Specifically, the variable labels under variance seem to be cut off the output page (photo in link below). Any suggestions for how to fix?

[image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unzAn.png)

Comment: (1) Shrink the font used on the console, then `options(width=...)` where `...` is some number larger than before. (2) I have no idea. I don't know how you created it or what else is going into this. Welcome to SO, please read links and suggestions that are presented to all new users here, including [help]. Further, I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Great suggestion! Running it tonight (overnight) with your recommendation. Thank you.  Thanks also for the gentle guidance.